# How to separate the data based on names present in a column?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-wrangling

I have a data frame that looks this.

```
df <- data.frame(names = c("Ram","Siddhharth","Nithin","Aashrit","Bragadish","Sridhar"),
                 house = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"))
```

I want to create a new data frame which gets re-arranged based on the house they are in.

Expected Output

```
house_A   house_B
1 Ram       Siddhharth
2 Nithin    Aashrit
3 Bragadish Sridhar
```

How can I achieve this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `df %>% group_by(house) %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = house, values_from = names, names_prefix = 'house_')` . This link has other options : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322801/transpose-reshape-dataframe-without-timevar-from-long-to-wide-format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Reshape data frame from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765323/r-reshape-data-frame-from-long-to-wide-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `tidyr`:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from="house", names_prefix="house_", values_from="names", values_fn=list) %>%
  unnest(cols=everything())
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  house_A   house_B   
  <chr>     <chr>     
1 Ram       Siddhharth
2 Nithin    Aashrit   
3 Bragadish Sridhar
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when I run the code.Error in values_fn[[value]] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

Comment: What's your package version? Please type in `packageVersion("tidyr")`.

Comment: Tidyr package Version  is 1.0.2

Comment: Please update your `tidyr` package to `1.1.0` and try again.